# How to bring back user to a menu after first selection

Tags: python

I have a short code that either calculates the area of a circle of a sphere. The user can select from 2 inputs. Once they have gone through either selection the program ends.

I want the program to ask the user again for input. I tried a while loop, but then I can't exit it.

```
import math

# menu options
print("********************")
print("**   my program   **")
print("********************")
print("1) Area of Circle")
print("2) Area of Sphere")
print("********************")

option = int(input("Please Pick an option: "))
if option == 1:
    radius = float(input("Please enter radius "))
    area = round((math.pi * radius**2),4)
    print("Area:",area)
elif option == 2:
    radius = float(input("Please enter radius "))
    volume = round(((4/3)*math.pi*radius**3),4)
    print("Volume:",volume)
else:
    print("Error - wrong number entered")
```

Comment: Please, provide your attempts with `while`. And when do you want to exist? Do you want to ask user twice, three times, or until user inputs "stop" (or something)?

Answer (score 0):

if you're having trouble ending the while loop, you just need to end it with a breaking condition

here is how you do it:

```py
import math

will_continue = True

while will_continue:
  # menu options
  print("********************")
  print("**   my program   **")
  print("********************")
  print("1) Area of Circle")
  print("2) Area of Sphere")
  print("********************")

  option = int(input("Please Pick an option: "))
  if option == 1:
      radius = float(input("Please enter radius "))
      area = round((math.pi * radius**2),4)
      print("Area:",area)
  elif option == 2:
      radius = float(input("Please enter radius "))
      volume = round(((4/3)*math.pi*radius**3),4)
      print("Volume:",volume)
  else:
      print("Error - wrong number entered")
      
  # ask if user wants to continue
  if input("Do you want to continue? (y/n) ") == "n":
      will_continue = False
  else:
      will_continue = True
```

Comment: You don't need an `else: will_continue = True` part. Also, you can avoid the additional `will_continue` variable if you use `while True` with `if input(...) == 'n': break`